# How can I prevent wordpress from creating tag pages?

Tags: tags

I use the built in wp tag functionality to group my posts thematically and then I use the WP_query to have the posts displayed according to custom design.  I do not need the tag pages created by default in wordpress and I would either like to have them NOT created at all (ideally)  or be able to add a noindex meta to the post, as these should not be indexed separately.  Is there some way to accomplish this?

EDIT:  one additional possibility I have looked at is to exclude all matching urls from the sitemap eg exclude all urls matchine /tag/* .  I use the Yoast plugin, but I don't see any filter which would allow me to do this type of exclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect from the automatically-generated tag archive pages, you can check to see if [`is_tag()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_tag/) is true in the [`template_redirect`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) action hook, and redirect with [`wp_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) if it is:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    if ( is_tag() ) {
        // Currently redirects to the site's home page.
        wp_redirect( '/' );
        // Use the 301 Permanent redirect if desired.
        // wp_redirect( '/', 301 );
        exit;
    }
} );
```

To exclude the tags from the sitemap generated by WordPress (Plan B in your question), you can use the [`wp_sitemaps_taxonomies`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_sitemaps_taxonomies/) filter.

```
add_filter( 'wp_sitemaps_taxonomies', function( $taxonomies ) {
    if ( ! empty( $taxonomies['post_tag'] ) ) {
        unset( $taxonomies['post_tag'] );
    }
    return $taxonomies;
} );
```